# Message: Incorrect syntax near 'ID'

Tags: c#, sql, syntax-error

Can I ask why a pop-up message pops up with an error near the `ID`?, I find no solution for this. It just pops up this message after i click the button.

> **Message:** **Incorrect syntax near 'ID'**

```
public override bool fnSaveNewRecord()
{
    DataSet _ds;
    string _sql;
    object _obj;

    _sql = "INSERT INTO do_information(die_class_code,subinvetory_code,contact_code,company_code, " +
           "corg_code,created_on,created_by) " +
           "VALUES '" + txt_CodeID.Text.Trim() + "','" + cbx_SubInventoryCode.Text + "'," + 
           "'" + cbx_ContactCode.Text + "','" + cbx_CompanyCode.Text + "','" + cbx_CorgCode.Text + "','" +
           "',GETDATE(),'" + App_Common._USER_CODE + "'";

    _ds = new DataSet();
    _obj = new SqlDatabase(App_Common._WSFCSConnStr) as SqlDatabase;
    _ds = ((SqlDatabase)_obj).ExecuteDataSetQ(_sql);

    return base.fnSaveNewRecord();
}
```

Comment: You need to use `VALUES ( v1, v2, ... )` - so with brackets.

Comment: You should really use a parametrized query instead of concatenating values into a query string. Your current solution is vulnerable to SQL injection, and a bad security practice.

Comment: Some OT remarks: a) you don't need `as SqlDatabase` as you already create one; b) you don't need `_ds = new DataSet();` as you will be *overwriting* that empty dataset in your ExecuteDataSetQ call; c) you don't seem to use that `_ds` (and you don't need it for an insert), is there a plain Execute method that you can use?

Comment: And using parameters will bring a much more readable statement. With that string concat mess you will not see the trees because of the forest :o)

Comment: And about the tags, this is not a C# syntax error. I've added SQL.

Answer (score 3):

**Try using this query:**

```
_sql = "INSERT INTO do_information(die_class_code,subinvetory_code,contact_code,company_code, " +
                "corg_code,created_on,created_by) " +
                "VALUES( '" + txt_CodeID.Text.Trim() + "','" + cbx_SubInventoryCode.Text + "'," + 
                "'" + cbx_ContactCode.Text + "','" + cbx_CompanyCode.Text + "','" + cbx_CorgCode.Text + "','" +
                "',GETDATE(),'" + App_Common._USER_CODE + "'"+ "')'";
```

You have missed using the brackets for `Values(v1,v2)` as @Peter B commented.
have a look at [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) for reference of SQL insert statement.

And it is always better to use parameterized queries than concatenated strings because, it is prone to SQL Injection Attacks.
[Here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Parameterized-queries-to-prevent-SQL-Injection-Attacks-in-SQL-Server.aspx) is a reference for using parameterized queries.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Your SQL statement is wrong because of the missing brackets for the values.

The code is very messed up and it is hard to see that at the first sight. So you better use parameters to have a more clean statement you can easily read and check for syntax errors:

```sql
INSERT INTO do_information 
    ( die_class_code, subinventory_code, contact_code, company_code, corg_code, created_on, created_by ) 
VALUES 
    ( @CodeId, @SubInventoryCode, @ContactCode, @CompanyCode, @CorgCode, GETDATE(), @UserCode )
```

But you can even do more to get this code clean. Wrap all your queries. Here an example for your statement:

Starting with some reusable base declarations

```
public interface IExecuteQuery
{
    int Execute();
    Task<int> ExecuteAsync( CancellationToken cancellationToken );
}

public abstract class SqlExecuteQuery : IExecuteQuery
{
    private readonly DbConnection _connection;
    private readonly Lazy<DbCommand> _command;

    protected SqlExecuteQuery( DbConnection connection )
    {
        if ( connection == null )
            throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( connection ) );
        _connection = connection;
        _command = new Lazy<DbCommand>(
            () =>
            {
                var command = _connection.CreateCommand( );
                PrepareCommand( command );
                return command;
            } );
    }

    protected abstract void PrepareCommand( DbCommand command );

    protected DbCommand Command => _command.Value;

    protected virtual string GetParameterNameFromPropertyName( string propertyName )
    {
        return "@" + propertyName;
    }

    protected T GetParameterValue<T>( [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null )
    {
        object value = Command.Parameters[ GetParameterNameFromPropertyName( propertyName ) ].Value;
        if ( value == DBNull.Value )
        {
            value = null;
        }
        return (T) value;
    }

    protected void SetParamaterValue<T>( T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null )
    {
        object value = newValue;
        if ( value == null )
        {
            value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        Command.Parameters[ GetParameterNameFromPropertyName( propertyName ) ].Value = value;
    }

    protected virtual void OnBeforeExecute() { }

    public int Execute()
    {
        OnBeforeExecute( );
        return Command.ExecuteNonQuery( );
    }

    public async Task<int> ExecuteAsync( CancellationToken cancellationToken )
    {
        OnBeforeExecute( );
        return await Command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync( cancellationToken );
    }
}

public static class DbCommandExtensions
{
    public static DbParameter AddParameter( this DbCommand command, Action<DbParameter> configureAction )
    {
        var parameter = command.CreateParameter( );
        configureAction( parameter );
        command.Parameters.Add( parameter );
        return parameter;
    }
}
```

Now define an interface for your statement

```
public interface IInsertInformationQuery : IExecuteQuery
{
    string CodeId { get; set; }
    string SubInventoryCode { get; set; }
    string ContactCode { get; set; }
    string CompanyCode { get; set; }
    string CorgCode { get; set; }
    string UserCode { get; }
}
```

The implementation

```
public class SqlInsertInformationQuery : SqlExecuteQuery, IInsertInformationQuery
{
    public SqlInsertInformationQuery( DbConnection connection ) : base( connection )
    {
    }

    protected override void OnBeforeExecute()
    {
        UserCode = App_Common._USER_CODE; // this should be injected
    }

    protected override void PrepareCommand( DbCommand command )
    {
        command.CommandText =
            @"INSERT INTO do_information ( die_class_code, subinventory_code, contact_code, company_code, corg_code, created_on, created_by ) " +
            @"VALUES ( @CodeId, @SubInventoryCode, @ContactCode, @CompanyCode, @CorgCode, GETDATE(), @UserCode )";

        command.AddParameter( p =>
        {
            p.ParameterName = "@CodeId";
            p.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String;
            p.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
        } );
        command.AddParameter( p =>
        {
            p.ParameterName = "@SubInventoryCode";
            p.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String;
            p.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
        } );
        command.AddParameter( p =>
        {
            p.ParameterName = "@ContactCode";
            p.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String;
            p.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
        } );
        command.AddParameter( p =>
        {
            p.ParameterName = "@CompanyCode";
            p.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String;
            p.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
        } );
        command.AddParameter( p =>
        {
            p.ParameterName = "@CorgCode";
            p.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String;
            p.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
        } );
        command.AddParameter( p =>
        {
            p.ParameterName = "@UserCode";
            p.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String;
            p.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
        } );
    }

    public string CodeId
    {
        get => GetParameterValue<string>( );
        set => SetParamaterValue( value );
    }
    public string SubInventoryCode
    {
        get => GetParameterValue<string>( );
        set => SetParamaterValue( value );
    }
    public string ContactCode
    {
        get => GetParameterValue<string>( );
        set => SetParamaterValue( value );
    }
    public string CompanyCode
    {
        get => GetParameterValue<string>( );
        set => SetParamaterValue( value );
    }
    public string CorgCode
    {
        get => GetParameterValue<string>( );
        set => SetParamaterValue( value );
    }

    public string UserCode
    {
        get => GetParameterValue<string>( );
        private set => SetParamaterValue( value );
    }

}
```

Finally your code would look like

```
public override bool fnSaveNewRecord()
{
    var database = new SqlDatabase(App_Common._WSFCSConnStr);
    using ( var connection = database.CreateConnection() )
    {
        connection.Open();
        IInsertInformationQuery query = new SqlInserInformationQuery( connection );

        query.CodeId = txt_CodeID.Text.Trim();
        query.SubInventoryCode = cbx_SubInventoryCode.Text;
        query.ContactCode = cbx_ContactCode.Text;
        query.CompanyCode = cbx_CompanyCode.Text;
        query.CorgCode = cbx_CorgCode.Text;

        var recordsAffected = query.Execute();
    }
    return base.fnSaveNewRecord();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is wrong:

```
  _sql = "INSERT INTO do_information(die_class_code,subinvetory_code,contact_code,company_code, " +
                "corg_code,created_on,created_by) " +
                "VALUES ('" + txt_CodeID.Text.Trim() + "','" + cbx_SubInventoryCode.Text + "'," + 
                "'" + cbx_ContactCode.Text + "','" + cbx_CompanyCode.Text + "','" + cbx_CorgCode.Text + "','" +
                "',GETDATE(),'" + App_Common._USER_CODE + "')";
```

Your values have to be in brackets. Have a look at this:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp